# Вопрос про работу метода foreach() интерфейса Iterable

Tags: java, list, foreach, lambda, лямбда-выражение

Есть такой код

```
 List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("eeny", "meeny", "miny", "mo");
        strings.forEach(string -> System.out.println(string));
```

Непонятно как он работает, за исключением того, что знаю что лямбда работает по той причине, что интерфейс Consumer является функциональным интерфейсом.

Но вот остальное как то очень запутанно. Возможно вся проблема в том, что у меня сложности в понимании следующего выражения находящиеся в интерфейсе Iterable

```
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {/*содержание тела метода 
                                                  мне понятна, поэтому не 
                                                  скопировал тут*/}
```

Просьба: Будет очень полезно, если пошагово напишите алгоритм работы данного кода.

Внимание: Если данный вопрос вдруг оказался дубликатом, тогда просто вставьте ссылку в комментах, без негативных голосов. Если содержание ссылки дает исчерпывающий ответ, тогда я свой вопрос удалю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поясняю, метод `forEach()` в качестве аргумента принимает `функциональный интерфейс`, а именно интерфейс `Consumer<T>`. Функциональный интерфейс - это интерфейс, который имеет только один метод. Для чего они нужны? В основном для лямбда-выражений. Итак, структура данного функционального интерфейса представлена следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, данный интерфейс принимает какой-то агрумента типа `T` и ничего не возвращает (`void`). Так же у него есть только один метод - `accept()`. Для "активации" нашего действия необходимо вызвать метод `accept()`, который нам бы пришлось реализовывать, например, с помощью анонимного класса, например вот так:

```
Consumer<T> cons = new Consumer<>() {
     public void accept(T arg){
         System.out.println(arg);
     }
 }
```

Согласитесь, не очень удобно каждый раз создавать анонимный класс. Но к нашему счастью лямбда-выражения освобождают нас от этой рутины. Чтобы выполнить этот метод нам достаточно просто написать: `s -> System.out.println(s)`. Где `s` - это аргумент, который мы передаем в наш фантомный метод `accept()`, а `System.out.println(s)` - 
это то действие, которые мы выполняем в этом методе `accept()`. Кстати, гораздо проще передать ссылку на метод: `forEach(System.out::println)`. В этом случае каждая перебранная переменная автоматические становится аргументом, который мы передаем в метод `accept()` и для каждой мы выполняем метод `System.out.println()`.

Answer (score 1):

[Use the Source, Luke](https://lurkmore.to/Use_the_Force,_Luke)

[Первоисточник](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Iterable.java) достаточно ясно показывает дефолтную имплементацию, а именно:

```
public interface Iterable<T> {
  default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (T t : this) {
        action.accept(t);
    }
  }
}
```

Грубо говоря, в кишках сидит конструкция `for-each`, которая работает через:

```
for (Iterator<T> t = iterable.iterator(); t.hasNext();) {
    T item = t.next();
    //blah-blah
}
```

Comment: Пардон, но вы невнимательно прочли мой вопрос. Выше я специально написал следующее " /*содержание тела метода мне понятна, поэтому не 
скопировал тут*/".  Мой вопрос не о том, на чем основывается работа foreach() метода, а на том, как именно он работает. Уточню: мой вопрос включает следующие непонятные для меня детали  1) "Consumer<? super T> action"  2) как лямбда выражение спокойно работает в качестве параметра foreach() метода. Это только те детали, которые я вижу как проблему, но возможно в ходе прояснений еще некоторые детали будут замечены.

Comment: Думаю можно и к числу этих деталей добавить и 3) параметр string в лямбда выражении, так как в функциональном интерфейса описан тип T, так откуда лямбда узнает какой тип надо присвоить к параметру string?

Comment: @RubenKubalyan тогда вы просто не понимаете как работают лямбда выражения, надо переформулировать ваш вопрос